# invalid csrf token express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning about backend and I have a problem with csurf protection in my express nodejs project. When I submit in add-admin form is working find, but add-product form and edit-product form I receive the error

> invalid csrf token
> 403
> ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token

this is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var  MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);


var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var userRouter = require('./routes/user');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
const Product = require('./models/product');

var app = express();  
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/project3', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs',expressHbs({defaultLayout:'layout', extname:'.hbs', runtimeOptions: {
allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true
}}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
secret:'mysupersecret', 
resave: false, 
saveUninitialized: false,
store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
cookie: {maxAge: 30*60*24*60*1000}
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());  
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/static',express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
res.locals.session = req.session;
next();
});

//routes
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

My admin.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var multer  = require('multer');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var async = require('async');
var {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var csrfProtection = csrf();
router.use(csrfProtection);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/project3', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

var Product = require('../models/product');
var User = require("../models/user");

// add-product page
router.get("/add-product",csrfProtection,
 function(req,res,next) {
    var messages = req.flash('error');
    res.render('admin/add-product', {
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), 
        messages: messages, 
        hasErrors: messages.length>0,        
    });
});


//edit-product page
router.get("/edit-product/:id", csrfProtection,function(req,res,next){
    Product.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.render("admin/edit-product", {
                csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), 
                editedProduct:data,               
            });
        }
    });
});


//delete a product

router.get("/delete-product/:id", function(req,res,next){
    Product.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
        if(err) {
        throw err;
        } else {
            res.redirect("../list-product");   
        }
    });
});


//list admin 
router.get('/list-admin', function(req,res,next){
    User.find({rule: 2}, function(err,admin){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            res.render('admin/list-admin', { 
                csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
                admin: admin
            });
        }
    });
});

// add account admin
router.get('/add-admin', function(req,res, next) {
    var messages = req.flash('error');
    res.render('admin/add-admin', {
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), 
      messages: messages, 
      hasErrors: messages.length>0
    });
});
  






module.exports = router;
```

my add-user.hbs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offet-3">
     
        <form action="/admin/add-product" method="post" id='checkout-form' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Tên sản phẩm</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
      
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Thêm sản phẩm</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit-product.hbs

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offet-3">
       
        <form action="../edit" method="post" id='edit-form' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="IDChar" value={{editedProduct._id}}>>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Tên sản phẩm</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" value="{{editedProduct.name}}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Thay đổi</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

add-admin.hbs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h3>Thêm tài khoản admin</h3>
        {{#if hasErrors}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{#each messages}}
                    <p>{{this}}</p>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <form action="/admin/add-admin" method='post'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id ="email" name = "email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Mật khẩu</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
            <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Thêm tài khoản Admin</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

i searched in google and document of csurf but i can't find resolve. Please help me, thank you for watching.